# Hot do I create a Web Site Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

***How do I create a Web Site using Visual Studio 2015?*** I don't see *Web Site* in the list of project templates.

My intention is to create a User Control that can be dynamically added to a Content Management System

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be at least a couple of ways of doing this.

If you already have a project and you wish to add a website to it you can right click on the solution  in the *Solution Explorer* pane to bring up the context menu, then *Add > New Web Site...*

If you wish to create a new project and add a Web Site to it, it seems that you can create a project of most any type and add a Web Site to it using the instructions I've just provided.

[image: Adding a Web Site to a Solution]